# mapping cone and cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given a map of spaces $f:X \to Y$, the mapping cylinder is the adjunction space 
$$cyl(f)=(X \times [0,1]) \cup_f Y$$
where we regard $f$ as a map $f: X \times \{1\} \to Y$.\
On the other hand the mapping cone is given by
$$cone(f):=C(X) \cup_f Y$$
where $C(X)=X \times [0,1]/((x,0) \simeq (x',0)$. 
Now I'd like to prove that $(cyl(f),X \times 0)$ is a good pair. 
How can I wite an explicit homotopy.

I proved that for example $cyl(f) \times 0 \cup X \times 1$ is a deformation retract of $cyl(f) \times [0,1]$. But I do not know if there is a link between these two things.

Furthermore, how could I prove the long exact sequence

$$...H_{n+1}(cone(f)) \to H_n(X) \rightarrow^{f_*} H_n(Y) \to H_n(cone(f)) \to...$$

I also know that the reduced homology of $cone(f)$ is isomorphic to $H_*(cyl(f), X)$.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question, note that for example the neighbourhood $ X \times [0,1/2) \subseteq cyl(f)$ of $X \times {0}$ deformation retracts onto it by the explicit $ (x,t,s) \mapsto (x,(1-s)*t) $.

Regarding the question about the long exact sequence, it follows from the above by the following observations:

1. The mapping cylinder $ cyl(f) $ deformation retracts onto $ Y $.
2. The homologies of homotopy equivalent spaces (e.g. deformation retracts) are isomorphic, hence
   $$
   H_n(Y) \simeq H_n(cyl(f))
   $$
3. The good pair discussed above $ (cyl(f), X \times {0}) $ gives rise to a long exact sequence of homology
   $$
   \ldots \rightarrow H_{n+1}(cyl(f),X \times {0})\rightarrow  H_n (X \times {0})\rightarrow H_n(cyl(f))\rightarrow H_n(cyl(f),X \times {0}) \rightarrow \ldots
   $$

Therefore, by using the last comment you wrote down, that is that 
$$
H_n(cyl(f),X)=H_n(cone(f))
$$
one obtains the long exact sequence above.